# Unable to setup ADFS on different domain and mvc app with window auth on different domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, wif, saml, adfs

My MVC 4 application (https://testapp.com) with WIF and windows authentication is on Domain A and my ADFS and users are on domain B.

Requirement: Users in Domain B will browse my application https://testapp.com  which is hosted in Domain A and my application should use their local windows user creds and redirect to the ADFS in Domain B.

I believe I dont require a AD cross Domain trust between A and B and that is what ADFS and SAML authentication is meant for.

I dont see such much materials for reference in such scenarios also. Kindly help understand how to configure such an MVC application in Domain A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to establish a trust between your MVC4 application and your ADFS. In ADFS lingo this is called "Relying Party". You will need to have an endpoint in your application that accepts a HTTP POST message and processes the payload generated by ADFS.

I had to recreate these a long time ago but you can spare the pain. There are more options available -
http://saml2.codeplex.com/ (open source)
http://www.componentspace.com/Products/SMLv20.aspx

Configuring ADFS can be tricky but there are lot of guides out there.

Comment: I have now established a relying party trust but show the redirection from my application to the adfs is not taking place. I dont know if this is a problem with my WIF installation on IIS? or is it because of the fedmetdata config issue, the fedmetadata config was issued to me by the adfs team.

Comment: How are you redirecting (meaning, in your app code or at IIS/router level) ?